# Spring boot application fails to run because of bean naming violation

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am getting this error :

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Configuration property name 'appConfig.baseVersion' is not valid:

    Invalid characters: 'C'
    Bean: paymentCheckoutRequestBuilder
    Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter

Action:

Modify 'appConfig.baseVersion' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.
```

paymentCheckoutRequestBuilder is a bean of class PaymentCheckoutRequestBuilder. How am I supposed to fix this , you cannot name a class in kebab-case.

Also, this error occurred after I tried upgrading my spring-boot to 2.2.0.

And what is this appConfig.baseVersion , not able to find anything online.

Answer (score 6):

property appConfig.baseVersion is in camel case so you should use use prefix in configuration as shown below

```
     mqConfig:
         enable: false
```

then your Configuration file must have `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mq-config")`

For current example the application.yaml should be

```
appConfig:
   baseVersion: 1
```

And java class should be

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app-config")
public class TestConfig {
  int baseVersion;
 }
```

And the

Answer (score 4):

this is self explanatory: Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case
Pay attention, that @ConfigurationProperties should not be in camel-case.
So you should fix prefix on @ConfigurationProperties for your target bean.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. For a long time I thought the problem was with `paymentCheckoutRequestBuilder`. The real problem was with `appConfig.baseVersion` which is defined as prefix in one of `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class. I changed the name and it worked.